# Bcrypt not working in Lumen 5.4: Call to undefined function bcrypt()

Tags: php, lumen

I created a new Lumen 5.4 project and tried to seed some data. In the seeder, I used bcrypt to hash the password. But when I run `php artisan db:seed`, I get this error:

```
Call to undefined function bcrypt()
```

Why can't I use bcrypt in Lumen? I have used it in Laravel previously.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You could try:

```
app('hash')->make('yourpassword');
```

Comment: True, this is more or less a workaround of the bcrypt implementation but why not use it directly?

Comment: really i don't know but what i know is `bcrypt()` in its source code returns this `return app('hash')->make($value, $options);`

Comment: Okay thanks! Might be worth adding that this is a work around so people will be aware of it.

Comment: Is there any way to get hash key. Actually, I took over someone's project and now getting same error and now the previous developer is not responding.  And I know what is encrypted key generated as I have access to database.

Answer (score 14):

another solution would be to use Facades\Hash

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
```

code

```
'password' => Hash::make('your_password')
```

Answer (score 9):

**Try to do it this way**

```
'password' => password_hash('123456', PASSWORD_BCRYPT)
```

Comment: This answer will marked as low quality. Please provide more information.

Answer (score -1):

try, I can do it fine in my project

```
 function bcrypt($value, $options = [])
        {
            return app('hash')->make($value, $options);

        }
```

Comment: Please provide more information to this answer. Also, to me this does not seem to be a real solution to the problem, just a quick workaround to "just get it running".

Comment: what should be included in options?